# Is it a bad practice to have a stateful helper class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a special case, as shown below.
I have Listener class, and an Uploader class. Listener class listens to messages over the network, processes them and creates another small object from that.

```
public class Listener {
    Uploader uploader;

    Listener(String location) {
        uploader = new Uploader(location);
    }

public void listen(Message msg) {
    ProcessedObject obj = process(msg);
    uploader.add(obj);
}

public void terminate() {
    if (null != uploader) {
        uploader.finish();
    }
}
```

}

The Uploader class takes one object via add method, and decides when to uploader. For this, it maintains a list. It also has location string, which is specific to one listener. Here's the gist:

```
/**
 * This class is not thread safe, and an object should not be shared across threads
 *
*/
public class Uploader {
    String location;
    List<ProcessedObject> objects;

    Uploader(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    void add(ProcessedObject obj) {
        objects.add(obj);

        if (objects.size() > PARTITION_SIZE) {
            uploadObjects(objects);
            objects.clear();
        }
    }

    void finish() {
        uploadObjects(objects);
    }
}
```

So, it uploads if the number of objects is greater than PARTITION_SIZE. There are multiple listeners in the application, each running on a separate thread. Each listener will have it's own uploader object. I have clearly mentioned that this class is not thread safe, in the javadoc.

Now my question is, is it a good practice?

Some of my colleagues say that this is not a good practice, and suggest to use a static method for uploading, and not create an instance of uploader. But my argument is, that will make my listener class messy (because then listener will have to maintain the counts, and check and upload again at the end before terminating for remaining objects)

With my approach, the whole partitioning and uploading logic is available in uploader class, so it improves readability as well as maintainability.

My question is, is my approach a bad practice (considering also that I specifically call out that uploader is not meant to be thread safe) ?

Also, is there any design pattern for what I am trying to do here? If yes, which one?

Edit: I accept I didn't frame the question properly. I am not concerned here about partitioning or the uploading. Just about the approach of creating one object of Uploader class per thread, vs making a stateless Uploader class with static methods to do the job.

Whether I uploading the remaining objects, or whether I should partition at all, are not the concerns of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine both approaches by using a private static [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to hold the Uploader.

**Looking at the bigger picture:**

I think your coworkers have a valid point. Consider that Uploader could be in a separate thread or pool of threads. This can all be abstracted away and hidden from Listener. Then Uploader can decide if it has enough work based on number of elements OR if it has been a set duration of milliseconds without receiving more elements. Maybe allow Listener to flush/finish but it shouldn't have to-- that kind of requirement is a gotcha for other coders.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, in that case I'll have to maintain a shared list of objects, which the uploader thread can monitor and upload at regular intervals. Is it that you are proposing?

Comment: @Kartik that's one possible implementation. or each listener thread could have an associated uploader thread(s). my point is that it should be completely transparent to Listener

Comment: This actually makes sense. But even in that case, It's the uploader that has to maintain the state for partitioning right?

Comment: @Kartik yes, of course. as long as the situation stays the same for your requirements (whatever is going on on your servers / networks that made you want to bundle the data in this way)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The bundling is to avoid the file to be uploaded to be too large.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ask this question in a wrong way. You ask if it is a bad practice or not.

Think the other way round. What is actually the task you are solving? Does the task make sense? And is your implementation good?

The task you are solving is "packaging" a few objects together for the upload instead of uploading them one by one.

This may totally make sense to reduce the number of uploads. But maybe not, it depends how much overhead a single upload costs. Knowing nothing more my assumption would be that it may totally make sense.

Now, is your implementation good? Well...

First of all you've mentioned multiple threads so you'll need to take extra care to synchronize on your list of objects.

Next, is it good to wait for `PARTITION_SIZE`? What if you've got just `PARTITION_SIZE - 1` objects`? You may wait for the last one forever, not sending the other objects.

Finally, what happens if your application goes down? You'll lose the data you've posted to the upload queue but not sent yet. And that may be really really bad. This solution is not reliable.

Comment: 1. I have a finish method to be called at the end, to give an opportunity to upload if the number of objects is less than PARTITION_SIZE

Comment: Are there guarantees on when `terminate` will be called?

Comment: 1. Like I mentioned, The uploader object is to be used inside 1 thread only. Thats the contract of that class, I have mentioned it twice in the question.

2. I have a finish method to be called at the end, to give an opportunity to upload if the number of objects is less than PARTITION_SIZE

3. Yes this might happen, We have our ways of retrying outside the scope of the given classes. And the data to be uploaded can be fetched again. So thats really not a concern for us

Having said all that, the question here is more about using static method vs the uploader object

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in the javadoc comment that it HAS to be called. but no programmatic checks (runtime or compile time) have been made. Is there any other way I can ensure that?

Comment: @Kartik better question is why create little dependencies and gotchas where there don't need to be any? see my answer as well

Comment: @Kartik *"the question here is more about using static method vs the uploader object"* - no, you were asking whether it is a bad practice or not.

Comment: @Kartik You have a false dilemma. It's not about  static method vs. uploader object. It's whether you need stateful partitioning or not.

Comment: @lexicore Yes, you are right. So, another question is, irrespective of the partitioning here. Is it a bad practice to have a stateful helper class like the one I created?

Comment: @Kartik If you have stateful stuff to do you will need a stateful tool. No way around that.